# Having trouble setting up SSL with Heroku + Namecheap

Tags: ssl, heroku

I'm trying to setup SSL for my website which is hosted on Heroku. So I clicked on the `Configure SSL` button and selected `Automatic Certificate Management (ACM)` and clicked next. It didn't give me any prompt after that but it now says that my certificate is automatically managed. Right under the SSL Certificates section, it shows the domains and it even says `Your app can be found at https://www.example.com` but when I try to visit the secure version, it gives me an error `NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID`.

Do I have to change anything regarding my DNS on the Namecheap side? So far all I have is a `CNAME` Record with the host set to www and it points to `heroku-generated-name.herokuapp.com.` and a `URL Redirect Record` with the host set to `@` and the value is `http://www.mywebsite.com`.

I searched online and one answer was to change the `CNAME` record to `heroku-generated-name.herokudns.com.` instead of keeping it `heroku-generated-name.herokuapp.com.`. I did this but then suddenly I started getting other errors like `DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN` whenever I tried to visit the page so I quickly changed it back. I'm not sure if it matters but I did notice that after I changed it to `*.herokudns.com.`, the `URL Redirect Record` was deleted so I'm not sure if that had anything to do with it. I didn't try messing with it any further so I just changed it back to `*.herokuapp.com.` and re-added the `URL Redirect Record`

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Hello, did you end up resolving your issue?